# Automating testing of a bot in facebook messenger using selenium. How to locate textbox for users and responses of bot?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

We are trying to automate testing of  a `facebook messenger bot` using selenium.

We are trying to locate the textbox of messenger using xpath but failing to do so.

Here is the `HTML` of the textbox:

```
<div class="_5rpu" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-label="Type a message..." aria-owns="js_6" role="combobox" spellcheck="true" style="outline: medium none; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="placeholder-jlsi" contenteditable="true">
```

We are new to selenium. Kindly help!

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to locate the textbox on Messenger.com (in Python) was with `switch_to_active_element`, since Messenger seems to make the textbox the active element by default.

E.g.,

```
textbox = driver.switch_to_active_element
```